# Is there a way to explicitly destroy all handlers pending on a given boost::asio::io_context?

Tags: c++, boost-asio

According to my knowledge and as far as I checked the boost::asio documentation and source code there is no way to destroy explicitly all pending handlers on a given io_context aside from destroying the context itself?

I need to be able, if possible, to stop the io_context, destroy the pending handlers on the io_context, then do some other things and finally destroy all io objects (timers, pipes, etc) associated with the given io_context and the io_context itself.

I know that I can use work_guard::reset and let all pending handlers to run and then the io_context will stop by itself, but the problem is that many of the handlers may produce (post/defer/etc) new pending handlers, etc i.e. each such handler will need to be guarded with something like 'if stopped'.

I think that the io_context::shutdown does exactly this but there is no way, aside from inheritance maybe, to call explicitly the shutdown function because it's not public.

Thanks.

Comment: The easiest way that comes to mind is to recreate a new instance of `io_context`

Comment: @sehe If I understand you correctly you propose some kind of explicit destruction of the io_context (unique_ptr<io_context>::reset, etc)? 
I thought about this but there are io_objects (timers mostly) which depend on the io_context and in this case they will need to be reset too before the io_context and it complicates the things a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying your suggestion using the protected `shutdown` results in a segfault on my system. I think it's protected for a reason :)

Anyhow, it looks like a judicious combination of `restart`/`stop`/`reset` might do the job. It's weird that some of the handler queue apparently stays around UNLESS one does a (empty) `run`/`run_one`. In fact even a `poll_one` seems to suffice. So, by all means, include that.

Here's my test bed code, you might find it useful:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/564b9b84464a5e7d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Handler {
    void operator()(boost::system::error_code ec) { std::cout << "Handler invoked: " << ec.message() << std::endl; }

    struct Instance { // logging only unique instance to avoid noise of moved handlers
        Instance()  { std::cout << "Created handler instance"   << std::endl; }
        ~Instance() { std::cout << "Destroyed handler instance" << std::endl; }
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Instance> _instance = std::make_unique<Instance>();
};

int main()
{
    struct Hack : boost::asio::io_context { 
        using boost::asio::io_context::shutdown;
    } io;
    auto work = make_work_guard(io);

    std::cout << " -- run" << std::endl;
    auto t = std::thread([&]{ io.run(); });

    {
        boost::asio::high_resolution_timer tim(io, 2s);
        tim.async_wait(Handler{});
        work.reset(); // no longer needed

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);

#if 1
        io.stop();
#else
        io.shutdown(); // segfaults
#endif
    }

    std::cout << " -- timer destructed" << std::endl;
    std::cout << " -- joining" << std::endl;
    t.join();

    std::cout << " -- empy run to flush handler queue" << std::endl;
    io.reset();
    //io.run();
    //io.run_one();
    io.poll_one();

    std::cout << " -- bye" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
 -- run
Created handler instance
 -- timer destructed
 -- joining
 -- empy run to flush handler queue
Handler invoked: Operation canceled
Destroyed handler instance
 -- bye
```

### UPDATE

Here's my best suggestion (apart from, I guess, [not sharing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/043e8b63ee98e52e) `io` at all):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/686a3a5914333f71)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct Handler {
    void operator()(boost::system::error_code ec) { std::cout << "Handler invoked: " << ec.message() << std::endl; }

    struct Instance { // logging only unique instance to avoid noise of moved handlers
        Instance()  { std::cout << "Created handler instance"   << std::endl; }
        ~Instance() { std::cout << "Destroyed handler instance" << std::endl; }
    };
    std::unique_ptr<Instance> _instance = std::make_unique<Instance>();
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::io_context> io;

    int i = 1;
    for (auto delay : { 1500ms, 500ms }) {
        std::cout << " ------------------- reinitialized -------------- \n";
        io = std::make_unique<boost::asio::io_context>();
        boost::asio::high_resolution_timer tim(*io, 1s);

        std::cout << i << " -- run" << std::endl;
        auto t = std::thread([&]{ io->run(); });

        tim.async_wait(Handler{});

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay);

        std::cout << i << " -- stop" << std::endl;
        io->stop();

        std::cout << i << " -- joining" << std::endl;
        t.join();

        std::cout << " ------------------- destruct ------------------- \n";
        io.reset();
    }

    std::cout << "Bye" << std::endl;
}
```

Prints

```
 ------------------- reinitialized -------------- 
1 -- run
Created handler instance
Handler invoked: Success
Destroyed handler instance
1 -- stop
1 -- joining
 ------------------- destruct ------------------- 
 ------------------- reinitialized -------------- 
1 -- run
Created handler instance
1 -- stop
1 -- joining
 ------------------- destruct ------------------- 
Destroyed handler instance
Bye
```

Comment: I find this behavior a bit surprising too. As far as I tested such solution, with post-ed handlers only, the handlers remained in the io_context queue even after reset and when I called io.run they got executed again. The problem is that the posted handlers have no way to know (unless explicit flag is used) if the context has been stopped and reset or not.

Comment: Yeah. Honestly, I'd do this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/686a3a5914333f71 (or not even sharing http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/043e8b63ee98e52e)

Comment: Seems that this is the best that can be done with the current io_context interface

Comment: Thanks! I had it all in place and could not always stop a service. By adding `poll_one` between `reset` and `join`, it no longer hangs. The devil is in the details.

Comment: @PavelVazharov I don't know, if that behaviour is so unexpected: `stop()` signals `run()` and friends to not process any more pending jobs and return instead. `reset()` just resets that stop bit, maybe, its name is a bit unclear. So just construct a new `io_context` whenever you need a clean one.